# Python - how to correctly set up hierarchy of classes?

Tags: python, class, subclass, super

I have the following code:

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class CPU(Computer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CPU, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name

mycomputer = Computer('My Computer')
mycomputer.CPU.name = 'Intel'

print mycomputer.name, mycomputer.CPU.name
```

I would like to get the following:

```
My Computer, Intel
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Computer' object has no attribute 'CPU'
```

How do I set up the class correctly, so once I run the main code, I would get what I need? I'm not even sure if I'm using super() correctly at all.

I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I don't think you want subclassing at all.

Comment: What method would allow you to use mycomputer.name, mycomputer.CPU.name?

Comment: you got wrong what subclasses are for, as Cyphase pointed out. What you want is just attributes to your Computer. Generally, think of classes as "blueprint" for something. A subclass is a specialized blueprint. For example, `mycomputer` is an implementation of the `Computer` blueprint.

Comment: Subclassing is if you have, for example, a class called `Computer`, and you want to make subclasses called `Desktop` and `Laptop`. `Desktop` and `Laptop` are subclasses of the more general class `Computer`. In turn, `Computer` is a subclass of the more general `object`. Note that doing `class Computer(object):` as you did does not give the `object` class or it's instances a `name` attribute.

Comment: Read about composition and inheritance. Also, `is a` and `has a` relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want subclassing at all.

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu

class CPU(object):
    def __init__(self, manufacturer):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer

intel_cpu = CPU('Intel')
mycomputer = Computer('My Computer', intel_cpu)

print "{}, {}".format(mycomputer.name, mycomputer.cpu.manufacturer)
```

Gives this output:

```
My Computer, Intel
```

Comment: Instead of passing in the `cpu_manufacturer` to `Computer`, you should pass the `cpu` itself. `my_computer = Computer('My Computer', CPU('Intel'))`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good point @MarkusMeskanen; I wasn't thinking that far for this answer :).

Answer (score 8):

The semantical problem in the hierarchy you built is the fact that `CPU` is actually not a computer type, it is a `part` of computer, so you should have defined it as an `attribute` instead of a sub type:

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu
```

Classes that are hierarchically related should have something in common even if they represent different things and have unique attributes that help us identify them. For instance; a car is a vehicle, a truck is also a vehicle so that vehicle can be defined as *super class* of both car and truck. Although they look totally different, they have something in common as vehicles: *engine*, *wheel*, *transmission* etc.

Getting back to you question, a CPU is basically a heart of computer, a *required thing for all type of computers* so it should be something that is inherited from super class `Computer`:

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu

class Laptop(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu, manufacturer):
        super(Laptop, self).__init__(name, cpu)
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer

class AutomatedTellerMachine(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu, bank):
        super(AutomatedTellerMachine, self).__init__(name, cpu)
        self.bank = bank
```

---

```
>>> macbook = Laptop('My Macbook', 'Intel', 'Apple')
>>> atm = AutomatedTellerMachine('ATM 1', 'AMD', 'Wells Fargo')
```

There is a good [read](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/) about class inheritance in Python. I'd strongly recommend to read it once.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your are mixin the inheritance concept and the composition concept.

let's say you have two classes A and B.
If class A inherits B then "A is a B" with more things. For instance a FrenchPerson class could inherit a Human class.

if class A compose B then A is made of B. For instance your Computer is a made with a CPU therefore

you should have something like

```
class Computer()
    def __init__(self, name, cpu):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu
```

haaa I am too slow to answer :D

Answer (score 2):

There are two different approaches for combining classes: inheritance and composition.

Inheritance is something like: there is a class `Computer`, which is subclassed or inherited by `Laptop` and `PC`.

Composition is something like: there is class `Computer`, which contains components like `CPU`, `RAM`, etc.

For your example you want to use composition. See @Cyphase's answer for a code example of composition.